# prevent collision of div in jquery while dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I have added preventcollision code but seems it is not working as both div are overlapping, what i want to do is drag "any1" and "any2" inside "col1","col2","col3" but they should not overlap and adjust themselves in container dropped.

**Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#any1").draggable({
    obstacle: "#any2",
    preventCollision: true
  });

  $("#col2").droppable({
    accept: "#any1"
  });


  $("#any2").draggable({
    obstacle: "#any1",
    preventCollision: true
  });

  $("#col2").droppable({
    accept: "#any2"
  });
});
```

```css
#any1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  left: 25px;
}
#any2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  left: 150px;
}
#col1 {
  width: 430px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  float: left;
  resize: none;
}
#col2 {
  width: 430px;
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  float: left;
}
#col3 {
  width: 430px;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="col1">
  </div>

  <div id="col2">
    <div id="any1"></div>
    <div id="any2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="col3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would appear that your snippet isn't working. I have updated the snippet, please check and confirm the correct changes were made.

Comment: Okay you have rejected the edit, the snippet isn't working...

Comment: those two div tags were moving in my code but by adding your snippets in script tag those are immovable and "draggable" is not defined in console after i run code adding your mentioned snippets.

Comment: Check your current snippet... It isn't working for me. When I edited your snippet I had it working hence asking you to confirm correct changes were made.

Comment: it isn't working for me i have checked in fiddle too,, the earlier one was working.

Comment: The snippet hasn't changed because you rejected my edit. The one I created was the working one. I see you have made the same changes I did in the request you rejected.

Comment: Please see the snippet now is it working for you?

Comment: Yes the snippet is now working as you have changed the snippet to match the changes I had made in the request.

Comment: Can you please solve the problem too ? :D